# How to select a value in a listbox and clone it with its optgroup label to another listbox

Tags: jquery, optgroup

I am currently working on a code that has two list boxes with option groups associated to each item. What I need is that when I click a value in listbox1 the value and its optgroup be clone in listbox2. The problem is that I don't know how to select current optgroup. When clicking over a value, how can I check if current optgroup exists in listbox2, if it exits just add the value and if it does not add the value and its outgroup. In the same way, if only one value is remaining in listbox1 when I click over the value, this and its optgroup be removed from listbox1.

I found this code on this forum and I was trying to adapt it to do what I need but I have been working around without any luck.

I will appreciate any help to solve this matter.

This is the code I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
 $("#lstBox1").click(function () {
   var selectedOp1 = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
   if($('#lstBox2 optgroup[label=Cars]').html() == null){
     $('#lstBox2').append('<optgroup label="Cars"></optgroup>');
           $('#lstBox2 optgroup[label=Cars]').append($(selectedOp1).clone());
        } else {
           $('#lstBox2 optgroup[label=Cars]').append($(selectedOp1).clone());
        }
   
        $(selectedOp1).remove();
    });

    $("#lstBox2").click(function () {
   var selectedOp2 = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
   $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOp2).clone());
        $(selectedOp2).remove();
    }); 
 
 
});
```

```css
#lstBox1 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;

}
#lstBox2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: #58A0DC;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox1'>

    <optgroup label="Cars">             
    <option value="40">Toyota</option>
    <option value="44">Ford</option>
    <option value="43">Kia</option>
    <option value="42">BMW</option>

    <optgroup label="Mortorcycle">
    <option value="16">Kawasaki</option>
    <option value="31">Suzuki</option>
    <option value="17">Yamaha</option>
    </select>



    <select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox2'>

    </select>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#lstBox1").click(function () {
     var selectedOp1 = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');

     if($('#lstBox2 optgroup[label=Cars]').html() == null){
       $('#lstBox2').append('<optgroup label="Cars"></optgroup>');
       $('#lstBox2 optgroup[label=Cars]').append($(selectedOp1).clone());
    } else {
       $('#lstBox2 optgroup[label=Cars]').append($(selectedOp1).clone());
    }

    $(selectedOp1).remove();
});

$("#lstBox2").click(function () {
     var selectedOp2 = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
     $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOp2).clone());
    $(selectedOp2).remove();
}); 


});
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code ? Are you getting any error? What error? Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: I just want to adapt this code to select current optgroup. For example: if you click over an option under the Motorcycle label in listbox1, it should add you the value and Motorcycle label into listbox2. Which this code does not do.

Comment: I just ran your code on a sample page and it worked fine for me. You can debug the code by 1. Seeing if you are getting any errors in Developer Tools Console of browser. 2. Put some alert statements in the code to see until when the code is running fine.

Comment: Hi Chetan. When you clic on a motorcycle value you should see the Motorcycle  label and the value in listbox No. 2 and you get Cars label that's the problem. I don't know how to get the value with its corresponding label in listbox No. 2.

Comment: `and you get Cars label that's the problem` this problem you have not mentioned in the question. So we really do not know what problem to solve. `$('#lstBox2').append('<optgroup label="Cars"></optgroup>');` will append only car `optgroup`. You dont have code to add option with `Mortorcycle` optgroup. So you have the logic problem not the code problem. Have a re-look at your code and logic to understand the issue and try to solve it.

Comment: Thanks Chetan. Now you understand my problem. In my example the Cars label  is a fixed value but the question is how to select the optgroup that belongs to certain value I click over and clone it to next listbox?   I wish, you could help with this.

Comment: `Have a re-look at your code and logic to understand the issue and try to solve it.` did you try this?

Comment: Hi Chetan. I almost got it. I just have to create a variable using this code to get optgroup label: var label = $(this).find("option:selected").parents("optgroup").attr("label");